# Subsetting in R using setDT to remove values

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I am using R studio to filter out varieties of wine that appear less that 5000 times in a dataset.

I have run the below function -

```
#create new data frame with varities greater than 5000
wineVar <- setDT(wineNew)[, if(.N > 5000) .SD, by = variety]
#list the unique varieties to show theres only 5
unique(wineVar$variety)
```

However when I try to see how many levels there are I still get the other 632 values.

```
[1] Cabernet Sauvignon       Pinot Noir               Chardonnay              
[4] Bordeaux-style Red Blend Red Blend               
632 Levels: Å½ilavka Agiorgitiko Aglianico Aidani Airen Albana AlbarÃ­n ... Zweigelt
```

Is there a way to completely remove these as it is causing issues with my training set - ie the training set still sees the values but with no data for dropped varieties.

Comment: Just refactor it.  As in `wineVar$variety <- factor(wineVar$variety)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this. You almost there.

```
wineVar <- setDT(wineNew)
wineVar <- wineVar[, .SD[.N > 5000], by = variety]
wineVar[, Variety:=as.factor(as.character(Variety))]
```

Comment: Thanks very much that solved my problem.

Comment: Another option, slightly simpler: `Variety := droplevels(Variety)`